# Can't access to list of data in angular typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I send a request to server and get list of data.

I need save this data in validable and use that in other the function of that file, but when i need to use that it show me empty list `[]`.

`tree:any[]=[];`

```
intialDataa(): any {
    this.claimsManagerService.getAll(this.searchParam).subscribe(data => {
        this.tree = data['records'];
        })
}
```

Now I need to use this data in other function:

```
    openAdd(id, par, title, nodel): void {
    console.log(this.tree)
    }
```

But it shows me in console the `[]`.

and when i console the `tree` in `InitalData()` it show me this :

```
  (74) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
length: 0
__proto__: Array(0)
```

**What's the problem? How can I use the `tree`????**

**Edit: Full Code:**

```
    intialDataa(): any {
    this.searchParam.page = 1;
    this.searchParam.rows = 1000;
    this.loading = true;
    let ddata;
    this.claimsManagerService.getAll(this.searchParam).subscribe(data => {
        this.InitData = data['records'];
        this.tree= data['records'];
        let treeData: FileNode[] = [];
        let queue: FileNode[] = [];
        while (this.InitData.length > 0) {
            let data = this.InitData[0];
            let node = {
                id: data.id,
                title: data.title,
                parentId: data.parentId,
                isChilde: data.isChilde,
                children: []
            };
            queue[node.id] = node;
            if (!data.parentId)
                treeData.push(node);
            else {
                // find parent
                let parent = queue[data.parentId]
                // add to children
                parent.children.push(node);
            }
            this.InitData.splice(0, 1);
        }
        this.rolesToTree(treeData)
    })
    this.tree = ddata;
}
```

And this is the second function:

```
    openAdd(id, par, title, nodel): void {
    console.log(this.tree)
    let cont = true;
    let item = nodel;
    let dialogRef;
    this.openNode.push(this.FindIndexWithParentId(nodel));
    console.log(this.openNode);
    while (cont === true) {
        if (item.parentId !== null) {
            this.openNode.push
                (this.FindIndexWithParentId
                    (this.treeControl.dataNodes.find(x => x.actionId === item.parentId)));
            item = this.treeControl.dataNodes.find(x => x.actionId === item.parentId);
        }
    }
    // this.openNode = this.treeControl.dataNodes.indexOf(nodel);
    if (typeof (id) === 'string') {
        dialogRef = this.dialog.open(ClaimsManagerAddComponent, {
            data: { id: null, isChilde: false, claimName: 'Main' }
        });
    } else {
        dialogRef = this.dialog.open(ClaimsManagerAddComponent, {
            data: { id: id, isChilde: false, claimName: title }
        });
    }

    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(res => {
        if (res) {
            this.intialDataa();
        }
    });
}
```

**HTMl Code :**

```
    <mat-progress-bar *ngIf="loading" mode="indeterminate"></mat-progress-bar>
<mat-tree #tree [dataSource]="dataSource" [treeControl]="treeControl">

  <mat-tree-node *matTreeNodeDef="let node" matTreeNodeToggle matTreeNodePadding>
      <button mat-icon-button disabled></button>
      <div class="hover">
        <div class="hover-items">
            <div class="label">
                <mat-label>
                  {{node.name}}
                </mat-label>
            </div>
            <div class="iconColor">
                <div class="add">
                    <mat-icon class=" icon-alien" (click)="openAdd(node.actionId,node.parentId,node.name,node)">add_circle_outline</mat-icon>
                </div>
                <div class="edit">
                    <mat-icon class=" icon-alien" [routerLink]="['/claims-manager',node.actionId,'edit']">edit</mat-icon>
                </div>
                <div class="delete">
                    <mat-icon class=" icon-alien" (click)="delete(node.actionId)">delete</mat-icon>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

  </mat-tree-node>
  <mat-tree-node *matTreeNodeDef="let node;when: hasChild" matTreeNodePadding>
      <button mat-icon-button matTreeNodeToggle [attr.aria-label]="'toggle ' + node.filename">
          <mat-icon class="mat-icon-rtl-mirror">
              {{treeControl.isExpanded(node) ? 'expand_more' : 'chevron_right'}}
          </mat-icon>
      </button>
      <div class="hover">
        <div class="hover-items">
            <div class="label">
                <mat-label>
                  {{node.name}}
                </mat-label>
            </div>
            <div class="iconColor">
                <div class="add">
                    <mat-icon class=" icon-alien" (click)="openAdd(node.actionId,node.parentId,node.name,node)">add_circle_outline</mat-icon>
                </div>
                <div class="edit">
                    <mat-icon class=" icon-alien" [routerLink]="['/claims-manager',node.actionId,'edit']">edit</mat-icon>
                </div>
                <div class="delete">
                    <mat-icon class=" icon-alien" (click)="delete(node.actionId)">delete</mat-icon>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </mat-tree-node>
</mat-tree>
```

Comment: Are the methods in same component?

Comment: @HarmandeepSinghKalsi yes man .

Comment: If possible the full code and how different methods are getting called. it is hard to understand with this much code

Comment: @HarmandeepSinghKalsi ok . wait

Comment: @HarmandeepSinghKalsi i update the question

Comment: How openAdd method is getting called?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216388/discussion-between-harmandeep-singh-kalsi-and-kianoush-dortaj).

Comment: @HarmandeepSinghKalsi in html  i call that

Comment: <mat-icon class=" icon-alien" (click)="openAdd(node.actionId,node.parentId,node.name,node)">add_circle_outline</mat-icon>

Comment: this.tree = ddata; remove this statement, ddata seems to be always undefined

Comment: @blazehub still not work man

Comment: this.tree= data['records']; verify whether response is being getting correctly map. Try consoling the response after assignment

Comment: @blazehub i console that it count `74` but when i click on that for see the items it not show me any things and it `lenght : 0 `

Comment: @blazehub `(74) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
length: 0
__proto__: Array(0)`

Comment: this.InitData = data['records'];
        this.tree= data['records'];
This seems to be problem...Try deep copying. It seems you are splicing the this.InitialData
this.InitData = [...data['records']];
        this.tree= [...data['records']];

Answer (score 0):

`this.tree` variable is assigned asynchronously. So by the time you try to access it in `openAdd()` functions, it still isn't assigned values. For a quick fix, you could make the call inside the `openAdd()` function directly.

```js
openAdd(id, par, title, nodel): void {
  this.claimsManagerService.getAll(this.searchParam).subscribe(data => {
    this.tree = data['records'];
    console.log(this.tree);
  });
}
```

We could improve the implementation using multicast observables like RxJS `BehaviorSubject`, but you need to show more details like how the functions are invoked.

Comment: no man . its not good way . i open the `openAdd` from html  .  when the `InitialData()` is complete worked render the html and i can call the `OpenAdd()`

Comment: i console the tree in InitialData but it sdhow me this `(74) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
length: 0
__proto__: Array(0)`

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I think you have reassigned the value for `this.tree = ddata`

Remove this line `this.tree = ddata` and try it...

Comment: Have you remove `this.tree=ddata` and try ? Because `ddata` compiler will assign `Undefined`.